# Where can I find file with UUID on OSX?

Tags: macos, uuid

On Linux I can get UUID are stored in some files on system (in example /var/lib/dbus/machine-id, /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid, /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id), can I find similar files on OS X?

Comment: What kind of UUID are you looking for? The files you've mentioned on Linux all serve different purposes.

Comment: I wanna identify in uniqe way machine. And I wanna read this ID from file on OSX

Comment: You could use the mac address.

Comment: @fr0g129 Two of the three files you mentioned on Linux don't uniquely identify the machine. (One is a random value generated at boot, and another is a random value generated every time the file is accessed!)

Comment: OK. Does OSX got similiar files? Do you know that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use uuidgen:

```
/usr/bin/uuidgen

$ uuidgen
6A786B80-8D52-4344-93D1-37C95F6C803A
```

Comment: ok I know I can use this, but I wanna find a file that contains UUID, in example uuidgen probably  store this ID in some file. On Linux we got this file /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems somewhat confused...

If you want to generate a unique UUID for some reason, use @ergonaut's answer:

```
uuidgen
70095BA9-B866-42F2-9DE4-606F54EBBA88
```

If you want to get a unique identifier for a particular CPU/machine, you can use the `system_profiler` like this:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

**Output**

```
Hardware:

Hardware Overview:

  Model Name: iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac12,2
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 3.4 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory: 16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: IM121.0047.B21
  SMC Version (system): 1.72f2
  Serial Number (system): DGKH80PXDHJW
  Hardware UUID: 1025AC04-9F9E-5342-9EF4-206EBAE40BF6
```

Or, if you want to select one of those values specifically, you can use:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/UUID/ { print $3; }'
1025AC04-9F9E-5342-9EF4-206EBAE40BF6
```

Or, you can use the MAC address of your primary Ethernet interface like this:

```
ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
3c:07:54:76:38:cd
```